# Determining the IP Address of the client in a WCF SOAP UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, soap

We are currently using a custom [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx).  This allows the consumer to specify the credentials in a SOAP header as follows:

```
<o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" mustUnderstand="1">
<Timestamp Id="_0">
    <Created>
        2013-04-05T16:35:07.341Z</Created>
        <Expires>2013-04-05T16:40:07.341Z</Expires>
    </Timestamp>
    <o:UsernameToken Id="uuid-ac5ffd20-8137-4524-8ea9-3f4f55c0274c-12">
        <o:Username>someusername</o:Username>
        <o:Password o:Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">somepassword
    </o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
```

We need to start logging the IP Address of the client, as well as doing some IP whitelisting/blacklisting.  Unfortunately I do not see how it is possible to retrieve the IP when in this class.  At runtime both the [OperationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current.aspx) and [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) properties are null.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress i` or `string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

Comment: HttpContext.Current is null at runtime when in this UserNamePasswordValidator

Comment: when you step thru the code and run it does it return your current username and password..? try debugging perhaps you are getting exceptions that's not being raised

Comment: When I step into the UserNamePasswordValidator the username and password are indeed passed to it (they are parameters on it)

Comment: is there anything else when stepping that the code jumps to for example `Page_Load` are there any `PostBack` etcll if you see it there perhaps you are clearing it somewhere is down the line in your code. look for things like `new` and are you storing the values in `Hidden-Fields` and or Session variables` can you show some of your actual .cs Code...?

Comment: Do you have the asp.net compatibility turned on?

Comment: There is no Page_Load or PostBack, this is WCF not ASP.Net.  There is no code to speak of, other than the web.config of behavior->serviceCredentials->userNameAuthentication setting which just specifies the class to use.

Comment: @Wiktor: asp.net compatibility is off

Comment: @Wiktor: you hit the nail on the head.  If I turn on compat mode I can now access the HttpContext.Current, and subsequently get the ip!  If you'd like credit you can create an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was to turn on the asp.net compatibility to get the http context back. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on ASP.NET compatibility mode, this give you access to the HTTPContext object.  The other way is the OperationContext.  It is a little odd, but you can use the following code to get the same:

```
var client = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
Console.WriteLine(client.Address); //This will get the IP Address
Console.WriteLine(client.Port); //This gets the port that the client has open
```

Comment: Hey, Wiktor noted the asp.net compat mode in a comment so I gave him the credit for the answer.  Also, as noted in the question, at the point where I need it the OperationContext.Current is null.

Comment: @csauve I will take a guess and say you didn't have the the SessionMode = SessionMode.Required property set on the ServiceContract attribute?

Comment: @Justin I had set SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, but operation context still null.